# Sample size calculation in AB testing

Tags: experiment-design, ab-test

In AB testing, how to calculate the minimum sample size? is there one standard way or there are multiple ways to do the calculation? Does the population size matter?

Comment: The sample will depend on how large of a difference you are looking to detect with a given confidence limit.  If the difference is large between A vs B then a smaller sample size can be used to.  If the difference is small, then a large number of samples are needed to separate the signal from the noise.  To estimate the required sample size with depend on what you are measuring and the shape of the sample distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate it. So the population size does not matter on choosing the sample size for AB testing, right? And why sample distribution matters?

Comment: Here is a pretty good link for a brief explanation/introduction: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/non-normal-distributions/.  If your sample sizes are large enough then central limit theorem works in your favor.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for your help. Have a nice weekend. :)